# cakephp dropdown list select and submit not working?

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, drop-down-menu, submit

I'm using cakephp1.3 and i want to display a dropdown in a view.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Ledger');?>
  <?php $userNames = $this->requestAction('users/getUsers'); ?>

  <fieldset>
    <legend><h2><?php __('Lend'); ?></h2></legend>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('burID'); ?> <br>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('displayname', array('type'=>'select','options'=>$userNames,'label'=>"Borrower",'empty'=>'Select name....')); ?><br>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('amount');?> <br>
    <?php echo $userNames;?> <br>
  </fieldset>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true)); ?>
```

it basically get users from Users database and display in a dropdown.Now i want to catch that selected name in the controller.but when i catch that from the controller it gives me the "displayname"(this is my fieldname which i imported to the drop down).How can i solve this?

Comment: Could you add the controller code, where you're trying to "catch" the dropdown value, to the question?

Comment: That is the question i have.

 `function add() {
  $userid=$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
  if($userid==null){ $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));}
  
  else {
   if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $this->Ledger->create();
    $len=$userid;
    $bur=$this->data['Ledger']['burID'];
    $amount=$this->data['Ledger']['amount'];
                                **$displayname=$this->data['User']['displayname'];**

          }`

this is my controller function.Can i acces to the "User" model in the "Ledger"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you shouldn't be going through

```
$displayname=$this->data['User']['displayname'];
```

Because you submitted the data through the form, you need to be retrieving data from through `Ledger`

```
$displayname = $this->data['Ledger']['displayname'];
```

Comment: i have done that.But it gives me the resutl as "displayname" if i select a name and submit.

Comment: In your original question, include the relevant controller code, and the output of `print_r($usernames)` in the view.

Comment: sorry your post is not clear to me.Can you please explain that to me?

Comment: If `$this->data['Ledger']['amount']` gives you the correct value, there's no reason I can see that `$this->data['Ledger']['displayname']` wouldn't give you the correct value.

Comment: i thought that because there were 2 databases involved."displayname" is in the Users database and amount is in the Ledgers database.isn't it @Alex?

Comment: `Ledgers` is a object that holds the values in the form. You're populating the form with values from the `users` database, but your the values of the form belong to `Ledger`, so when the form is submitted you need to use the `$this->data['Ledger']` object to retrieve submitted values.